# How to hold animation when the animation is running in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

For example, the translate transform animation is running, I want to hold on the animation, but not to stop it, how to do with that?

Comment: Did you mean you want to *pause* or *temporarily stop* the animation?

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to pause in animation worked correctly you need to call the Begin() method from the code, such as `Loaded` event handler (eg: `Window_Loaded`), because - quote from [`MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms605764%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> When you Begin a storyboard that was paused, it appears to resume and restart. However, that is not what actually happens. The Begin method actually replaces itself with an unpaused version. *Each time the Begin method is called, clock objects are created for the storyboard.* These clocks are distributed to the properties they animate. So, when the Begin method is called again, it does not restart its clocks; it replaces them with new clocks.

Example:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="SomeStoryboard">
        ...
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
```

In `Loaded` event or something else:

```
MyStoryboard = (Storyboard)this.FindResource("SomeStoryboard");
MyStoryboard.Begin();
```

And in `Pause` Button:

```
private void ButtonPause_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyStoryboard.Pause();
}
```

For more information, please see:

[`MSDN: Storyboard.Pause Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms605764%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)